# Returning API response correctly from Update method. Postgres db pg-promise Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm just starting with building APIs, node.js, postgres so this might be a bit of a naive question..
I have noticed that when I call the update method and no record is found the method throws an error, and I was expecting a null result, where I would send a 404 response. I was just wondering if this (returning a response from an error) is considered bad practice and if I shouldn't just perform two queries instead, the 1st to check if record exists and the 2nd to update it.
Here's my update method

```
exports.updateProductById = async (req, res) => {
  const productId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const { productName, quantity, price, city, region, country } = req.body;



  await db.one({
    name: 'update-product',
    text: 'UPDATE products SET productName = $1, quantity = $2, price = $3, city = $4, region = $5, country = $6 WHERE productId = $7 RETURNING productId, productName, quantity, price, city, region, country',
    values: [productName, quantity, price, city, region, country, productId]
  })
    .then(result => {
      console.log('update-product:', result);
      if (result != null) {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: 'Product Updated Successfully!',
          data: result
        });
      }
      else {
        // not called
        res.status(404).send({
          error: 'Product not found.'
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('update-product error:', error);
      // workaround
      res.status(404).send({
        error: 'Product not found.'
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: You're essentially setting a catch-all error handler for the whole promise chain. Do you know for sure that the only instance this promise chain will throw is in the case where the product is not found?. Also, you'd be handling a failed updated scenario here - is 404 actually the right http header in this case?

Comment: Indeed that's not the only error it could throw.. namely a non nullable parameter passed to the api.. I guess I should set up a switch for error handling/response returning.

Comment: So not getting a null but an error it is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I don't know much about the postgres api, so I couldn't tell whether that should actually be the expected behaviour. But this makes sense in some extent, since it may consider this as some sort of a failed precondition for an update operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have noticed that when I call the update method and no record is found the method throws an error, and I was expecting a `null` result.

Why were you expecting that? Documentation for method [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one) tells you clearly right from start:

> Executes a query that expects exactly 1 row to be returned. When 0 or more than 1 rows are returned, the method rejects.

If you want `null` when no records returned, there is method [oneOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#oneOrNone).

Comment: thanks for the explenation. I got confused with `one` as i read that basically was a short for `oneOrNone` method. I'll use that one instead then. Many thanks for the help. Cheers.